# How to change MainPage from another page Xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms

I created a new Xamarin Form project with Master-Detail template.
In the project has MainPage, MenuPage. 
It runs fine but after i change MainPage in App.cs to my LoginPage then when i click to item in the Menu it raise error that MainPage is null.
here is the code in MenuPage

```
public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage
{

    MainPage RootPage { get => Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage; }
    List<HomeMenuItem> menuItems;
    public MenuPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        menuItems = new List<HomeMenuItem>
        {
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Browse, Title="Browse" },
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.About, Title="About" }
        };

        ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = menuItems;

        ListViewMenu.SelectedItem = menuItems[0];
        ListViewMenu.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                return;

            var id = (int)((HomeMenuItem)e.SelectedItem).Id;

            await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu(id);
        };
    }
}
```

App.cs

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
        MainPage = new LoginPage();
    }
```

here is MainPage.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    Dictionary<int, NavigationPage> MenuPages = new Dictionary<int, NavigationPage>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;

        MenuPages.Add((int)MenuItemType.Browse, (NavigationPage)Detail);
    }

    public async Task NavigateFromMenu(int id)
    {
        if (!MenuPages.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case (int)MenuItemType.Browse:
                    MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new ItemsPage()));
                    break;
                case (int)MenuItemType.About:
                    MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new AboutPage()));
                    break;
            }
        }

        var newPage = MenuPages[id];

        if (newPage != null && Detail != newPage)
        {
            Detail = newPage;

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                await Task.Delay(100);

            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
}
```

LoginPage.cs

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
    }
}
```

i think my problem in this line code

```
MainPage RootPage { get => Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage; }
```

cus MainPage is no longer MainPage in the app.cs Please Help

Comment: You know exactly what the problem is.  Application.Current.MainPage is not always of type MainPage.  Sometimes it is type LoginPage.  Your code is making an assumption that is not always true.

Comment: Hi, thanks Jason, Yes, i created just a button await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage()); directly to MainPage without login. so the MainPage alway LoginPage(). So how to  fix if this scenario

Comment: if your MainPage is always a LoginPage, then your RootPage property should probably return a LoginPage.

Comment: Yes. So let say. If my mainpage is p1. I have button in p1 navigate to p2. So how can change p2 to mainpage when im in p2.

Comment: I Add additional code. please have a look. When i click to Menuitem its raise error in this line MainPage RootPage { get => Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage; }

Comment: How are you able to click on a menu item from your login page?  Is it also a MasterDetail?

Comment: my MainPage,xaml <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <views:MenuPage />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>. I create button from LoginPage navigate to MainPage

Comment: when im in MainPage,i click to the Menuitem it is error. but when i change MainPage = new MainPage() in app.cs; it works fine. but i want uses start from my LoginPage not a MainPage. The problem MainPage RootPage { get => Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage; }  here is the RootPage is not a MainPage, its a LoginPage so error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, if you want to display LoginPage, then navigating to MasterDetailPage, I suggest you can use another way to display MatserDetailPage, don't use Visual Studio Xamarin.Forms MasterDetail template.

MainPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetailPageNavigation;assembly=MasterDetailPageNavigation"
              x:Class="MasterDetailPageNavigation.MainPage">
 <MasterDetailPage.Master>
<local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:ContactsPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>

 public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        masterPage.listView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP)
        {
            MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;
        }
    }

    void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
            masterPage.listView.SelectedItem = null;
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
}
```

MasterPage:

```
 <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="listView" x:FieldModifier="public">
       <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:MasterPageItem}">
                <local:MasterPageItem Title="Contacts" IconSource="contacts.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:ContactsPage}" />
                <local:MasterPageItem Title="TodoList" IconSource="todo.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:TodoListPage}" />
                <local:MasterPageItem Title="Reminders" IconSource="reminders.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:ReminderPage}" />
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="5,10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

There is one sample that you can take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page